# Adobe Acrobat insert text in a new doc.txt

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I'm trying to save text to a new doc in adobe acrobat with javascirpt, but i can't undestand how to do that.
I created a new file in this way:

```
var doc = app.newDoc();
```

How can i insert text in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acrobat JavaScript does not have access to the base plane where text etc. is residing.

What you can do is create a text annotation, place it, and finally flatten the document.